# Add space before GirdLayout which is inside ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout, android-scrollview

I want to add some space before the GridLayout starts and I want to fit a button and textview there. I tried adding Space before GridLayout, but it didn't do anything. I could make a button and textview as 2 elements inside grid, but the positioning is then awkward.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="16"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    (children)
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: You can use LinearLayout or ConstraintLayout in ScrollView

Comment: Oh now I see. I should close the LinearLayout after GridLayout, now it works.